# Can I safety travel with an external hard disk drive in a backpack?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Verbatim 500GB external hard drive, and I'm thinking about putting games on it and bringing it to school. Will having this in a backpack which is moved somewhat a lot, hurt the drive?

Comment: You shouldn't be playing games at school :/

Comment: I refer to a question I answered [How does a laptop with HDD function when it's moving?](http://superuser.com/questions/632526/how-does-a-laptop-with-hdd-function-when-its-moving) because of the similar nature and the links I provided in there.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Solid State drive, no it shouldn't be an issue as long as it doesn't take too much abuse.  They do make Hard Disk drives which are pretty durable (and designed for transport), but they have moving parts and are far more incined to fail.

Also, keep in mind your school/work may have IT security policies in place against bringing in outside storage (like thumdrives, CD's, and hard drives).

Comment: It is a normal hard drive (not an SSD).

Comment: If you're not concerned with drive failure, and that you won't be breaking any security policies...  Yea, it'll do.  But, if you want reliability, get a "rugged" hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I used to take my external HD to school, because I had to copy a lot of files (development tools) and downloading them was painful with my slow internet. The drive only broke when I dropped it on the floor at home, and had no failures nor badblocks or anything in almost 1 year of this routine.

I guess it's pretty safe. Of course, I used a very soft backpack and put the drive on a slot solely for it, and took really care of it.

Oh, and take care with viruses, they are a pain.

Comment: Windows != viruses. Security is as weak as the weakest link in its enforcement, in other words generally the user, not the Environment.

Comment: I didn't say Windows = viruses, but it's more than common sense that public computers are a virus den and also Windows is much more susceptible to them than Linux, BSD and other systems. I'm not blaming the system, I'm blaming bad faith.

Comment: Windows is much more susceptible because of user habits, things have changed in the computer world. Your final line suggests there is an incessant problem with Windows, and there is not.

Comment: Are you happy now?