# Moving a laptop while chkdsk is running

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, chkdsk

I have been having some issues on my computer for a while, and in an attempt to fix it, I decided to run `chkdsk C: /f /x /r` to see if anything there was causing problems. I started this when I arrived in the morning assuming it would be done by home time, but it is still running. It is currently at 24% and has been for several hours (in the past, it has done similar things, but at different percentages), the HDD activity light is constantly on, and the spinner is spinning away. But thanks to some bright spark at Microsoft, Windows 8 chkdsk does not give you any verbose output except for `scanning and repairing drive`

As its running on `C:`, the system had to reboot, and then run the tool.

So, now that make-a-move time is approaching, I am unsure as to whether I should leave the laptop here and let it run overnight, or take it back with me tonight and leave it running at home. But, my concern is, while the disk is so active, would it be risky to move the laptop (via a backpack) during this time?

** EDIT **

As luck would have it, 2 minutes before I left, it completed. Jumped straight to 100% and booted straight up, total time: 6 hours 30 minutes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it harmful to laptop to move it when it's working?](http://superuser.com/questions/136413/is-it-harmful-to-laptop-to-move-it-when-its-working), also see [How does a laptop with HDD function when it's moving?](http://superuser.com/questions/632526/how-does-a-laptop-with-hdd-function-when-its-moving)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chkdsk hanging issue aside: it is a most reasonable rule to avoid giving shock to a HDD as much as possible, especially while it is running, as it is in your case. Check out how HDDs are built and you will see why: the head hovers very closely above a spinning platter and any shock can cause the head to scratch the surface. And you want to avoid that :)

Not knowing where the mentioned 'here' is, it's rather difficult to recommend leaving the equipment overnight. If it's safe to leave the computer wherever you are right now, it's better to leave it there and come back in the morning than take it in a backpack with a spinning hard drive.

Comment: 'here' is effectively a fortified bunker, so its safe here. yeah, thought it would be along those lines

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, if the HDD is mechanical at least, moving it will either disrupt the process anyway or you will damage the HDD.

Comment: sounds like its best to leave it where it is then